# Out of memory Importing a large data set

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, knex.js

I have a node ETL script that imports a large number of records (somewhere north of 1 million) in ~1000 batches of 1000 items. To do so, it:

1. Requests the first batch. This provides the first 1000 items and tells us how many batches we need to import and the total number of records available to us.
2. Imports the first batch of 1000 records.
3. Iterates over each additional batch and imports the records in that batch.

The problem is that I'm running out of memory after processing ~80 batches (less than 10%!) and I think it's a problem with how I've structured the code. Like something's accumulating behind the scenes and I've lost all ability to recognize it any longer. Here's the basic code:

```
getBatch(1)
    .each(function(item, i, total) {  // always 1000 iterations
        return save(item);
    })
    .then(function() {
        // Return an array of batch numbers left to be imported
        // In this case, batches 2 through ~1000. The totalBatches value
        // is saved to an in-scope variable within the getFirstBatch()
        // function.
        return Array.from(new Array(totalBatches - 1).keys(), x => x + 2);
    })
    .each(function(batchNumber, i, batchCount) {  // Just over 1000 iterations
        return getBatch(batchNumber)
            .each(function(item, i, total) {  // Always 1000 iteractions until the last batch
                return save(item);
            });
    })
    .tap(function(importedBatchNumbers) {  // Not even close to getting here
        // Do a few minor cleanup operations
    })
    .then(function(importedBatchNumbers) {
        // Summarize
        totalBatchesImported = importedBatchNumbers.length + 1;

        console.log('...');
    })
```

Maybe there's a better way to approach this that I haven't considered? I'm using The bluebird library for promises and Knex to handle the database activity.

At this point, all I really know is that I'm not even close. The work gets done properly, but nowhere near enough of it. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between (1) "1000 items" and (2) "1000 records"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: "records" = "items". Apologies if I wasn't consistent with the terminology.

Comment: It's possible that you are just victim of lazy GC. If so, then introducing some artificial delay may give GC the opportunity to do its thing.

Comment: Another thought - do `getBatch()` and/or `save()` grab resources (eg database connections) that need to be released?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't seem to account for any kind of asynchronous process. As fas as I can tell, as soon as this runs it will try to process all 1000 batches at once, causing it to crap out when it can't do any more simultaneously (~80).

You need to ensure that each batch has actually finished being processed before you initiate loading the next one.

Chunking large data-sets like this can be handled well using a [Stream](http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/).

You can also use libraries to [chunk the data for you](https://github.com/Olegas/node-chunking-streams)

Comment: Hmmm. You know, I may not be thinking about this correctly, then. I thought  (and my output seems to indicate) that the batches (and items within each batch) are being processed sequentially.